# How to create Dependent Select Field With using Jqfancyfield library?

Tags: jquery, yii

How to create Dependent Select Field With using Jqfancyfield library?I am using jqfancyfield library in Yii.
here is my Html in Yii

```
<div class="col1">
    <?php 
        echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'car_id', 
             CHtml::listData(NewCar::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'), 
             array( 'prompt' => 'Select Car','class'=>'selectcar', ));
        echo $form->error($model, 'new_car_id');
    ?>
</div>
```

the Ajax Request which invoked on selecting any value

```
$('.selectcar').fancyfields({
    onSelectChange: function (input, text, val) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl(' / site / variantOfCar '); ?>',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            data: {
                new_car_id: val
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#Insurance_variant_id").setOptions(data.dropDownVariants);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: i am getting TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e in jquery.js